# The price you pay to have someone watch over you

Tags: riddle, word, wordplay

**Who or what am I?**

> I'm no lawman, no soldier, no hero standing tall.
>
> Yet each must pay this price in turn, to have somebody to watch over us all.

Hints:

> The answer is a single word, nine letters.

> The answer involves wordplay. The answer is a word in itself, but also a portmanetau of two shorter words which are the answers to the second line.

Happy to offer hints, incorporate feedback if given!

Comment: @luxmi12, have you cracked the riddle? Or are you affiliated with the OP?

Comment: @CodeNewbie I've not cracked the riddle, no. The OP added some hints, I just altered the formatting :)

Answer (score 12):

You are a

> **Vigilante**. Not a lawman, soldier or hero.

When you watch over someone, that is a

> vigil

And the price we all pay is

> ante, all the players in poker have to pay the 'ante' to play

And so the price you pay for someone to watch over you is literally a

> vigil ante.

Comment: what's more, the "in turn" hooks in very nicely to your paying explanation

Comment: Congratulations! I'd give you the tick if i'd somehow not messed up and created two different accounts with the same name somehow...

Comment: @Micat http://puzzling.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts

Answer (score 5):

The price we pay is

> Death

Reasoning:

> Death is definitely not a lawman, soldier, nor a hero. And everyone dies at some point. When we die, we can a) take this in a religious direction and say that either God or Satan is watching over us or b) take it in a literal direction and say that people will be watching over us at the funeral/the burial.

Comment: FWIW, I suspect reading your answer led my subconscious to the answer I've given below. Funny how that works.

Answer (score 5):

First,

> I have interpreted "each ... in turn" to refer to the subjects of the first line ("lawman, soldier, hero"), rather than to "us all" in the second.

Thus, my answer is

> "Lifeguard"

because

> Police (lawmen), Soldiers and other hero-types all dedicate their lives to guarding everyone else's.

Comment: +1, this has to be the right answer. At the very least, as a nine letter word which answers the riddle, it should have more than one upvote after a day.

Answer (score 2):

The price we pay for someone to "watch over us all" is

> taxes - you are the IRS.

I'm no lawman, no soldier, no hero standing tall.

> the "taxman" does not make laws, just enforces them. He doesn't fight, and is typically not considered a hero

Yet each must pay this price in turn...

> As each of us grow older, and can no longer be considered a dependent, we must begin to file for taxes (I admit, not everyone is taxed, so it doesn't quite fit here)

to have somebody to watch over us all

> Our tax dollars fund government agencies, including the long reach of the NSA, which actively engages in domestic surveillance (as famously exposed by Edward Snowden recently)

Comment: We don't pay taxes "in turn". And each of us don't pay tax. The poor are not taxed.

Comment: Would it be possible for you to edit this answer to include a more detailed explanation as to how it answers the question? Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I guess it is

> Shelter (as in Residence, house)

I'm no lawman, no soldier, no hero standing tall.

> Not a person.

Yet each must pay this price in turn, to have somebody to watch over us all.

> Guards us against Climate, Animals and dangers. I am reading in turn as in generation by generation residing take turns to pay based on whoever is the bread earner of the family.

Comment: Again, why "in turn"?

Comment: @JaviMartínez Good point.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe it is

> a prayer

And you are

> God

```
I'm no lawman, no soldier, no hero standing tall.
```

> God isn't a lawman or a soldier, and he isn't considered as a hero (correct me if I am wrong)

```
Yet each must pay this price in turn, to have somebody to watch over us all.
```

> God is listening to everyone, especially if we pray to him

Comment: Please explain how your answer fits each line. In its current form, this answer has very little information.